# How can I switch to lg viewport for the print preview on bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

It seems that the print view of bootstrap switches to xs automatically when I'm trying to print the site, is there a way to make the print view be the lg viewport instead?

something like

```
@media print {
  .container {
    @media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
      width: $container-lg;
    }
    @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
      width: $container-lg;
    }
    @media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {
      width: $container-lg;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Printing is tricky with most browsers - the issue is that depending on browser, default paper size and it's orientation (portrait or landscape) a page will print in 72ppi, 96ppi or 144ppi.

In Bootstrap the media query establishes a pixel width band... e.g. "xs" is between 544px-767px, so depending on the (printed) page width your site might revert to the "xs" or the "sm" width variants when printing.

Your attempt is pretty much spot-on... just (remembering that we can't predict the px width of a print) I would consider printing full page width regardless of fluid or not (i.e. printed pages would always be fluid).

Assuming you have access to the source .less files, try something like...

```
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins/grid-framework.less";
@import "mixins/grid.less";

@media print {
  .container,
  .container-fluid {
    .container-fixed();
    width: auto;
    min-width: 750px;
  }
}
```